# Generar números aleatorios de tipo entero en un intervalo

Tags: kotlin

¿Cómo se puede generar en Kotlin números aleatorios de tipo entero dentro de un intervalo de valores?

Se desea que el intervalo de valores sea semiabierto, osea en *notación matemática*:
 `[a, b)`.
Esto quiere decir que se puede incluir el valor inicial pero no el valor final del intervalo.

Por ejemplo, si se pide un número aleatorio para el intervalo **entre 10 y 13**, el valor podrá ser: `10`, `11` ó `12`

Comment: agregué una respuesta, espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 3):

Puede crear una [función de extensión](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) similar a [`java.util.Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) pero que tome un [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/) en lugar de `Int`:

```kotlin
fun Random.nextInt(range: IntRange): Int {
    return range.start + nextInt(range.last - range.start)
}
```

Ahora puede usar esto con cualquier instancia de [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

```kotlin
val random = Random()
println(random.nextInt(10..13)) // prints 10, 11, ó 12
```

Si no desea tener que administrar su propia instancia de `Random`, puede definir un método de conveniencia utilizando, por ejemplo, [`ThreadLocalRandom.current()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#current--):

```kotlin
fun randomInt(range: IntRange): Int {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(range)
}
```

Ahora puede obtener un número aleatorio como lo desea:

```kotlin
randomInt(10..13) // returns 10, 11, ó 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar a como se realiza en [Android con Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android):

```
Random r = new Random();
int valor = r.nextInt(13- 10) + 10;
```

La versión en Kotlin sería:

```
var r = Random()
var valor = r.nextInt(13- 10) + 10;
```

Pero puedes también hacer uso de una función como esta que propongo:

```
fun valorRandom(valores: IntRange) : Int {
    var r = Random()
    var valorRandom = r.nextInt(valores.last - valores.first) + valores.first
    return valorRandom
}
```

Para llamar esta función y mostrar el resultado en el `LogCat` se realiza de esta forma:

```
 Log.i("Random", valorRandom(10..13).toString())
```

como resultado se obtendrán valores de 10 a 12.