# No se muestran las notificaciones en Kotlin al pulsar boton

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, notificaciones, aplicación-movil

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Kotlin con Android Studio. He realizado una pequeña app para crear y borrar tareas y ahora estoy con el tema de las notificaciones. De momento me gustaría simplemente que al crear una tarea inmediatamente me aparezca una notificación. He seguido [esta](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification?hl=es-419) la guía de android studio, pero no se por qué no me funciona. ¿Saben que me falta para conseguirlo? No recibo ningun error.

Evento SetOnClickListener del boton para añadir la tarea.

```
       btn_añadir_tarea.setOnClickListener {
        val hora_añadir_tarea = sp_hora.selectedItem.toString()
        val minuto_añadir_tarea = sp_minuto.selectedItem.toString()

        if (titulo_añadir_tarea.isNotEmpty() && descripcion_añadir_tarea.isNotEmpty() && hora_añadir_tarea != null && minuto_añadir_tarea != null) {


            val db = DB(applicationContext);
            try {
                db.añadirTarea(applicationContext, titulo_añadir_tarea.toString(), descripcion_añadir_tarea.toString(), dia, hora_añadir_tarea, minuto_añadir_tarea )
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                val notificar = Notificacion(applicationContext)
                notificar.crearNotificacion("prueba", "prueba")


            } catch (e: Exception){
                Log.d("Error añadirTarea: ", e.toString())
            }


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ha habido un error al crear la tarea $descripcion_añadir_tarea", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

}
```

Clase Notificacion.kt

```
package com.example.listadetareas


import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
import android.os.Build
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import kotlin.with


class Notificacion(val context: Context) {

    init {
        createNotificationChannel()
    }
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = context.getString(R.string.titulo_notif)
        val descriptionText = context.getString(R.string.descripcion_notif)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(name, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
     fun crearNotificacion(title: String, descripcion: String) {
         var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.descripcion_notif))
             .setContentTitle(title)
             .setContentText(descripcion)
             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
         with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
             val notificationId = title.hashCode()
             notify(notificationId, builder.build())
         }
    }
```

}

La función añadirTarea (añade la tarea a la base de datos SQLite) se ejecuta correctamente y el Intent tambien, pero no se crea posteriormente la notificacion.

Si necesitan algo más no duden en pedirlo. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado el fallo. El problema era por un lado, que no había establecido un icono, ya que pensaba que no era obligatorio. Por otro lado, no había nombrado al CHANNELID de createNotificationChannel igual que el de crearnotificacion(), por eso no me dejaba.

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

El problema se encuentra aquí, **el método [notify(int id,
Notification notification)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) debe recibir como `notificationId` un valor entero y tu estas enviando un valor de tipo HashCode.**

```
val notificationId = title.hashCode()
notify(notificationId, builder.build())
```

Debes asegurar que ese valor sea entero y debe ser diferente entre cada notificacióon para evitar que se sobreescriban. Puedes declarar una variable y esta incrementarla cada vez que creas una notificación.

```
var idNotification:Int = 1
...
...
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
...
...
  notify(notificationId, builder.build())
  notificationId++  
...
...
}
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu respuesta. El resultado es el mismo. Se ejecuta todo perfectamente pero al crear una tarea no me sale la notificacion. Por otro lado, titulo.hashcode() me devuelve un entero ya que al pasar el cursor por la variable en Android Studio me devuelve : **var notificationId: Int**

Comment: Imprimiste el valor de title.hashCode() solo para asegurar en realidad sea un valor numerico?

Comment: el output es -979635247 pero ponga lo que ponga siempre me da este resultado el hashcode

Comment: Es muy raro, ya que al ser un hash me deberia dar combinaciones diferentes no?

Comment: Permiteme revisar, veo que si te da el mismo valor, 1) deberías tener un valor diferente y el valor entero debe ser positivo, permite revisar para darte otra opción.

Comment: de acuerdo, gracias

Comment: Me he fijado en la primera solucion que me has mandado. Es normal que me dé siempre 1, ya que aunque despues el valor se incremente en uno, va a volver a pasar por _var idNotification:Int = 1_, así que su valor volvera a ser 1 siempre. Lo he hecho con la [funcion Random](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/generar-números-aleatorios-de-tipo-entero-en-un-intervalo), que me da un numero positivo, varía y la probabilidad de coincidir es bastante baja (me sirve ya que simplemente es de prueba) pero me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Ya revise: 1) title.hashcode() siempre da el mismo valor porque tiene siempre el mismo texto, 2) Para que no de siempre el valor de 1 esto debe ser definido afuera del método: var idNotification:Int = 1

Comment: De acuerdo, creo que este problema está solucionado ya. Ahora me da otro error, pero ya lo soluciono por mi cuenta, gracias!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127736/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-angel).